# Error: Too many values to unpack with CSV File

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

my program shown below has the goal of outputting statements based off two criteria:(`Year` and `Location`) Once that was accomplished, my next goal is to match `year` with `Yearlink` and `Location` with `location`. `location` and `year` are both input statements. The output should be a statement that outputs values from that row. For some reason, I always receive an error about too many values to unpack. My excel sheet is posted if anyone wants a better idea of what I am talking about.[image: Excel Sheet] Anyway I tried everything but nothing was working for me.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/RoszkowskiM/Desktop/win4.py", line 134, in <module>
    for From,To,Max,Min in data:
ValueError: too many values to unpack



LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE = 'C:\Users\RoszkowskiM\Desktop\Data_2016.csv' # CSV File to Read
    # read the entire CSV into Python.
    # CSV has columns starting with Year,busnum,busname,scaled_power,tla,location
    data = list(csv.reader(open(LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE)))
    mydict = {}
    for row in data:
        Year,busnum,busname,scaled_power,tla,Location,Yearlink,From,To,Max,Min = row[0:12]



    #If this is a year not seen before, add it to the dictionary
    if Year not in mydict:
        mydict[Year] = {}

    busses_in_year = mydict[Year]
    if Location not in busses_in_year:
         busses_in_year[Location] = []


    #Add the bus to the list of busses that stop at this location
    busses_in_year[Location].append((busnum,busname,scaled_power))
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------



#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#User Input Statement
year = raw_input("Please Select Year of Study: ")
print("\n")

commands = ["Millwood-Buchanan", "Astoria-East-Corona", "Bronx", "DUNWOODIE-North-Sherman_Creek",
            "Vernon", "Greenwood-StatenIsland","West_49th","East_13th","Staten_Island","East_River",
            "East_View","DUNWOODIE-SOUTH","Corona-Jamaica","Astoria-East-Corona-Jamaica",
            "Astoria-West-Queensbridge-Vernon","Astoria-West-Queensbridge"]
max_columns = 50

for index, commands in enumerate(commands):
    stars_amount = max(max_columns - len(commands), 0)
    row = "# {} {}({})".format(commands, "." * stars_amount, index + 1)
    print(row)
location=raw_input(" \n The list above show the TLA Pockets as well as the ID numbers assigned to them ()\n\n Please enter the ID #: ")
print("\n")
Year=year
Location=location




if Year in mydict and Location in mydict[Year]:  
    busses_in_year = mydict[Year]
    print("Here are all the busses at that location for that year and the new LOAD TOTAL: ")
    print("\n")


#Busnum, busname,scaled_power read from excel sheet matching year and location

for busnum,busname,scaled_power in busses_in_year[Location]:
    scaled_power= float(scaled_power)
    busnum = int(busnum)
    print('Bus #: %d\t' % busnum ,'Area Station: %s\t'% busname,'New Load Total: %d MW\t' % scaled_power)
else:
        exit


for row in data:
    Year,busnum,busname,scaled_power,tla,Location,Yearlink,From,To,Max,Min = row[0:11]

    if Yearlink==year and Location==location:
            for From,To,Max,Min in data:
                From=int(From)
                To=int(To)
                Max=float(Max)
                Min=float(Min)
                print('From Bus #: %d\t' % From ,'To Bus #: %d\t'% To,'VMAX: %d pu\t' % Max, 'VMIN: %d pu\t' % Min)                                                                

else:                                                                                                               
    exit
```

Comment: Please always post the Traceback in your question.

Comment: Have you tried to [catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect the variables to see what is happening?  Do you understand what the exception means?

Comment: You should always try to include some example data that we can use to test your code; in the case of a spreadsheet, convert a portion of it to csv and post it. [mcve]

Comment: I posted the traceback. The excel sheet is posted. I only posted a snippet of it because it is over 1000 lines of data.

Comment: Your screenshot stops at column K but I'm curious if you have data in columns after that?

Comment: No there is no data after column K. I wish I can attach my excel sheet so people can view it

Comment: Is `data` a list of lists?  Are there more than four *sub-lists*?  Two lines above the errant line, you extract those values from the current row - why aren't you using those?

Comment: data just represents one list. it's one CSV sheet.

Comment: I'm assigning the values as integers and floats b/c some of my data has decimal points

Comment: @wwii, Can you explain your question a little bit more? I am not quite understanding it.

Comment: the reason I called data twice in my program was b/c I did not know what other way I can execute the second part of my code. Because of the if statements. Any insight on how to change it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: as @wwii says: why aren't you use the values you are extract from the  row?. Simply delete `for From,To,Max,Min in data:` and correct the indent.

Comment: Did you write this??

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)? That variable unpacking does seem like a bit of a code smell, and would be much more subject to errors, as opposed to just loading the entire row into a dictionary.

Comment: how would i do that for my case?